# Is there a word for something which will run before and after an event?

Tags: meaning

If concurrent means two things running at the same time, is there a single word for something which will occur before and after an event?

E.g. 
Running concurrently with the show will be a bar open for refreshments. / 
The bar will be open [before and after] the show for refreshments.

Comment: In certain informal contexts one might say "bookend".

Answer (score 2):

Addressing the question in the title, the prefix *[peri-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=peri-&allowed_in_frame=0)* (“word-forming element meaning "around, about, enclosing”) often is used as a modifier referring to times or things near some event or thing (as in, eg, *[perinatal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perinatal)* (“Of or pertaining to the time around birth”), *[pericardium](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pericardium)*, etc).

However, *peri-* doesn't fit into the main question's context in an obvious way.  (Suggestions in other answers, such as Preetie's *pre-launch* and *post-launch* and Mario's *[circum-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=circum-&allowed_in_frame=0)*, seem better suited for the main question than is *peri-*.) For the example sentence, the current wording with *before and after* seems likely to be the most concise and suitable arrangement.

Again addressing the question in the title, the terms *setup* and *teardown* often are used to denote preparation before an event, and removal of equipment, etc, after it.  Terms *[runup](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/run-up#Noun)* (“A period of time just before an important event”) and *[buildup](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buildup#Noun)* also are used.

Answer (score 2):

*Before and after* is concise, and unambiguous, probably the best way you can describe something that runs before and after another event.

***Circum-*** is sometimes used to describe this notion *before and after* eg in morphology you have the **[circumfix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumfix)**, an affix that occurs on *both sides* of the base, or before and after the base if you will.

And there is a word ***circumcurrent*** which might fit your needs, but I have only seen it used in descriptions of *melodic movement*, as when a movement is ascending and then descending.

Answer (score 2):

Pre and Post seem to be the most used prefix/suffix.

"Pre-launch and Post-launch parties."

Answer (score 2):

How about "Pre" and "Post"? For instance, if it is a party it would be "pre-party" and "post-party"

Comment: 'Pre- and post-party' would work

Comment: What's wrong with 'before and after'?

Comment: Kathy I would appreciate it you read the answers and not repeat them in a hurry to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The show will be flanked by an open bar.

Comment: That would imply that there's an open bar off to the side.